# Plot multiple seaborn kde grouped by a variable

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm having some troubles trying to plot multiples kde from seaborn. I'm currently working on this database about Pokemons :

https://github.com/GaetanLF/Fill-the-Pokedex/blob/main/PokemonNew.csv

Then, I am trying to plot kde which represent HP by Generation (1 kde when Generation =1, 1 when Generation = 2 ect.). I tried different specifications and read seaborn's documentation but I don't figure out how could I do this. The most relevant code I've tried was :

```
sns.kdeplot(x=df["HP"],data=df.groupby(['Generation']))
```

Which returned me a single kde :

[image: KDE]

How could I discriminate by Generation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `hue` option:

```
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='tip', hue='day')
```

Output:

[image]